# convert jstl function to freemarker

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, freemarker

I need to trasform a jsp page to a freemarker template. I make use of some jstl functions which I need to bring inside freemarker and I need some help to write the freemarker code that does the same call to the actual jstl   inside the jsp. 
Any help is appreciated.

taglib.tld

```
<taglib>
...
<function>
 <name>isBeanType</name>
 <function-class>my.BeanUtils</function-class>
 <function-signature>boolean isBeanType(Object,String)</function-signature>
</function>
...
</taglib>
```

jsp snippet to transform in Freemarker script:

```
..
 <c:if test="${t:isBeanType(bean, 'my.BeanClass')}">
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Freemarker 2.23.22, it supports custom JSTL functions. So you can use it like this:

```
<#if t.isBeanType(bean, "my.BeanClass")>
  ...
</#if>
```

See the "FreemarkerServlet improvements:" section [1] for detail.

[1] http://freemarker.org/docs/versions_2_3_22.html

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker can easy call static methods with or without parameters:

http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_methodcall

, so just implement isBeanType method somewhere in model and call it.
Here is full standalone sample:
http://www.egtry.com/tools/freemarker/intro/method